# I am trying Substrate Kitties Workshop

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-front-end, kitties, substrate-kitties-chain, kitties-tutorial

I am trying substrate kitties Workshop. After setting environment  and paste the bare-bone code of kitties pallet , when I run `cargo build --release` the following error occur after 2-3 minutes when building `sp-runtime`:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `H256: TypeInfo` is not satisfied
   --> /home/abuzar945/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/a3ed011/primitives/runtime/src/testing.rs:260:14
    |
260 |     type Hash = <Header as traits::Header>::Hash;
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `TypeInfo` is not implemented for `H256`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `TypeInfo`:
              &T
              &mut T
              ()
              (A, B)
              (A, B, C)
              (A, B, C, D)
              (A, B, C, D, E)
              (A, B, C, D, E, F)
            and 117 others
note: required by a bound in `traits::Block::Hash`
   --> /home/abuzar945/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/a3ed011/primitives/runtime/src/traits.rs:917:5
    |
904 |     type Hash: Member
    |          ---- required by a bound in this
...
917 |         + TypeInfo;
    |           ^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Block::Hash`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `H256: TypeInfo` is not satisfied
   --> /home/abuzar945/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/a3ed011/primitives/runtime/src/traits.rs:700:16
    |
700 |     type Output = sp_core::H256;
    |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `TypeInfo` is not implemented for `H256`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `TypeInfo`:
              &T
              &mut T
              ()
              (A, B)
              (A, B, C)
              (A, B, C, D)
              (A, B, C, D, E)
              (A, B, C, D, E, F)
            and 117 others
note: required by a bound in `traits::Hash::Output`
   --> /home/abuzar945/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/a3ed011/primitives/runtime/src/traits.rs:665:5
    |
654 |     type Output: Member
    |          ------ required by a bound in this
...
665 |         + TypeInfo;
    |           ^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Hash::Output`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `H256: TypeInfo` is not satisfied
   --> /home/abuzar945/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/a3ed011/primitives/runtime/src/traits.rs:727:16
    |
727 |     type Output = sp_core::H256;
    |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `TypeInfo` is not implemented for `H256`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `TypeInfo`:
              &T
              &mut T
              ()
              (A, B)
              (A, B, C)
              (A, B, C, D)
              (A, B, C, D, E)
              (A, B, C, D, E, F)
            and 117 others
note: required by a bound in `traits::Hash::Output`
   --> /home/abuzar945/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/a3ed011/primitives/runtime/src/traits.rs:665:5
    |
654 |     type Output: Member
    |          ------ required by a bound in this
...
665 |         + TypeInfo;
    |           ^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Hash::Output`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `sp-runtime` due to 3 previous errors
```

Comment: Please add more details about your errors. Which substrate versions(branch) do you use? Which repo do you refer?

Comment: Repository is substrate package

Comment: Please give the link that you fork/clone

Comment: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/tree/tutorials/solutions/kitties

Answer (score 2):

This looks an issue with mismatching versions

In your error you complained about sp-runtime:

```
sp-runtime = { version = "5.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", tag = "devhub/latest" }
```

And you can see to sp_core:

```
sp-core = { version = "5.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", tag = "devhub/latest" }
```

I would suggest to delete Cargo.lock and the folder target:

```
rm -rf target && rm Cargo.lock
```

And build it again:

```
cargo build --release
```

You might need to update more later too, if you have more errors.